# A question about algebraic closed field and algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am taking 4th field theory, and I am trying to solve a problem:

Find a counter example for the following false statement: If $K$ is algebraically closed and $F \subseteq K$ is a subfield of $K$, then $K$ is an algebraic closure of $F$.

I tried many examples, like $\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$, but none of them satisfy the requirement. Can somebody help me cook up a counter example? Thanks!

Comment: Consider an algebraically closed but *transcendental* extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: For example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: That is (i) not a transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and (ii) not algebraically closed. So.... no?